# jQuery: link loses its class's clickability when appended

Tags: jquery

Here is my AJAX call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/cms/get_news'); ?>',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
                $('ul#news').append(
                '<li id="' + json[i].article_id + '"><a class="deleteItem" title="Delete Item" href="#">Delete</a> 
<a id="editItem" title="Edit Item" href="#" target="_blank">Edit</a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank">' + json[i].title + '</a></li>'
               );               
                 }
         },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            //alert('Error: ' + status + ' ' + error);
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
```

My question is this:  When I have just a regular link with a class of "deleteItem", it fires a deleteItem click event.  The event works fine.  But when the HTML is added programatically through jQuery, the link is not clickable any more.  Why is it not clickable.  It's like jQuery isn't recognizing it.  What do I need to do to make the event fire?  I tried adding the class programatically  but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements added dynamically to the dom should use `.on` for jQuery v1.7 and `.live/.delegate` for older versions.

Please note that for older versions, using `.delegate` is preferred over using `.live`

In your case it should be,

Using `.on` (jQuery v1.7)

```
$('#news').on ('click', '.deleteItem', function () {
 //delete code
});
```

For older versions using `.delegate`, [preferred method]

```
$('#news').delegate('.deleteItem', 'click', function () {
 //delete code
});
```

or using `.live`,

```
$('.deleteItem').live ('click', function () {
 //delete code
});
```

Comment: from the docs: "Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`."

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks, SKS.  Especially for reminding me that .on only works in 1.7.  We're still on 1.6.  Time to update.

Comment: @ZachL I agree and I edited my post to mention that .delegate is preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `click()`, attach the event handler with [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I tried $('.deleteItem').on(function() { ... } and $('.deleteItem').on('click', function() { ... } and neither worked.

Comment: hmmm... try:  `$('.deleteItem').on('click', function(event) { ... } `

Comment: That syntax of `.on()` is exactly equivalent to `.click()`. See my answer for more information. (Or read the doco.)

Answer (score 0):

well, this is what's happening

1. page DOM loads
2. you add .deleteItem click handlers
3. you add dynamically html

so of course, the items you added in (3) don't have any click handlers. What you need to do
is to add click handlers after you `append` the html code (or look at `$.live`)

Comment: `live` is deprecated in 1.7, use `on()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how your link works, but I assume you attached a handler to the original ".deleteItem" link using `.click()` or the non-delegated form of `.on()` - either of which only apply to elements that existed at that time. If you add new elements dynamically (e.g., after an Ajax call) you need to bind a click handler after they are added (e.g., within your Ajax success handler). Alternatively, you can use delegated events:

```
$("#news").on("click", ".deleteItem", function() {
    // your delete handling code here
});

// OR for jQuery versions older than 1.7
$("#news").delegate(".deleteItem", "click", function() {
    // your delete handling code here
});

// OR for really old jQuery versions
$(".deleteItem").live("click", function() { ... });
```

With [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) the handlers are bound to the container object and will automatically apply to the any child objects that match the second selector whether they exist on page load or are added later. The `.live()` function is deprecated, but is your only choice before version 1.4.2 - it works in a similar way but binds the handler to the document so it's much less efficient.